# Having trouble with local variables, needing to reference a variable as global within a function but I know it's not good practice

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting json data from a web page and then storing it. My code works 100% fine except when I try to increase number of errors. When I remove the `number_of_errors += 1` everything is dealt with effectively so I am pretty sure my issue is just down to global and local variables.

My code structure is as follows:

```
def scrape():
    try:
        # too much code here to post but this just scrapes data
        store()
    except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
        number_of_errors += 1


def store():
    # too much code here to post but this just stores data


def scrape_and_store():
    number_of_errors = 0
    while number_of_errors < 10:
        scrape()
        store()
```

With this code structure I get: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'number_of_errors' referenced before assignment` so I had an idea to add in `global number_of_errors`:

```
    except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError
        global number_of_errors
        number_of_errors += 1
```

But as far as I am aware this is poor form and can get me into trouble.

What is the best way to deal with this variable? I can't declare it in either `scrape()` or `store()` because then it will just reset each loop of the `while` statement, won't it?

Comment: Why not include it in function header? def scrape(number_of _errors): and later return it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch the exception `JSONDecodeError` in `scrape_and_store()` like this:

```
def scrape():
    # too much code here to post but this just scrapes data


def store():
    # too much code here to post but this just stores data


def scrape_and_store():
    number_of_errors = 0
    while number_of_errors < 10:
        try:
            data = scrape()
            store(data)
        except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
            number_of_errors += 1
```

That way neither `scrape()` nor `store()` need to know how to count errors.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Marcus.Aurelianus for his comment.

I included the variable in the function header and made use of `return`. The following seems to be working:

```
def scrape(number_of_errors):
    try:
        # too much code here to post but this just scrapes data
        store()
        return number_of_errors
    except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
        number_of_errors += 1
        return number_of_errors


def store():
    # too much code here to post but this just stores data


def scrape_and_store():
    number_of_errors = 0
    while number_of_errors < 10:
        number of errors += scrape(number_of_errors)
        store()
```